# Weird behavior of code, working fine on local but not working on stage

Tags: c#, node.js

We are calling a Node api from C# code, that node API returns 2 things i.e.one string and one array of objects. This object inside array contains 2 properties, one is and Id and second one is an URL. We iterate this array of object on c# side and display each URL on UI.

Node's code is already deployed to stage so when I am using that api on local and running C# code locally it is working fine and we are able to see all the URL's on UI.

But when this same c# code is deployed to stage its is not showing any URL and behaves like Node API haven't returned anything. This is really weird, I am not getting what is an exact issue.

C# code to get data from Node API:

```
MLCPolicyResponse mlcPolicyResponse = new MLCPolicyResponse(); 
            string apiURL = string.Format("inventory/getCampaignPolicyAndAssets?campaign_id={0}", criteria.CampaignId);
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequestPolicy = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(MLConsoleAPI + apiURL);
            httpWebRequestPolicy.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            httpWebRequestPolicy.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequestPolicy.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequestPolicy.Headers.Add("Authorization", MLCHeader);
            var responsePolicy = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequestPolicy.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Hey, do you have any error logs we can have a look at to better help you? Also can you confirm that MLConsoleAPI is pointing to the right URL?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.